# IOS - Media Player stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, media-player

I have added the MediaPlayer library and written the code to play a video in fullscreen mode.

I also added a button in my view which is linked to a function that fires up the MediaPlayer with an external Video URL. Now I am sure the code is correct because MediaPlayer is being loaded into the screen, and if I try a wrong URL it will display an error.

The problem is, the MediaPlayer is stuck and display at the top **"Loading..."** all the time. I tried to play the video in my browser and it worked. I also tried a different video from another server in the browser and it worked too, but never in MediaPlayer.

Also, clicking the "Done" button in MediaPlayer has not effect and doesn't return me to the view I was in before launching it! It keeps MediaPlayer on screen all the time with that "Loading..." stuck.

I am using XCode 4.5 and IOS Simulator 6.0

Comment: got the same problem: did u ever found a solution?

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry I didn't notice your reply. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This answer really helped me.

[mediaplayer framework not playing video in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243903/mediaplayer-framework-not-playing-video-in-ios-6)

Added the controller and loaded it from the UIViewController instead of another UIView was the key to success in my case.