# mediaplayer framework not playing video in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, media-player, loading

I am using the mediaplayer framework included in iOS 6 to try and play a movie from within an app. I import  and then:

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"buyTutorial" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}
```

The view goes to blank screen and infinite loading when this function is called. I have tried many other versions of this implementation and the results vary and all fail. The log in the is particular case is:

```
2012-11-05 21:19:27.900 [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-11-05 21:19:27.902 [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-11-05 21:19:27.977 [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-11-05 21:19:27.978 [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-11-05 21:19:27.984 [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-11-05 21:19:28.156 [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

Got ideas on the cause? This is my first venture into playing video and it has turned out to be a nightmare at this point.

Comment: try with calling the `[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];`

Comment: Added [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay] but this did not change the result.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549143/playing-a-downloaded-video-from-the-documents-directory-with-cocoa-touch

Comment: the allocation and get path for movie player set view did load,only call [moviePlayerController play] to click button

Comment: @NANNAV I tried this, still didn't work. Different errors...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In .h file add the following

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *controller;
```

try this

```
 -(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
    {
        NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"buyTutorial" ofType:@"mov"];
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayerController play];
[self setController:moviePlayerController];
    }
```

Comment: Cannot build your code because class does not contain any method setController

Answer (score 0):

```
Am facing the same issue, you can else try playing it on the web view. 

   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filePath];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.docWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is that the variable "moviePlayerController" is just local scope, so right after you invoke `[moviePlayerController play];` and exit the function the local variable was release (because there is an asyn operation here with play method to play from queue). It doesn't keep content refer to URL anymore. So you see a black screen and an infinitive "Loading..."

You need to declare an instance variable of class and copy the content from local variable to class's property, like the example code from @iAppDeveloper above. It should work!