# MPMoviePlayer shows a solid black screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, media-player

I am currently working on an app in which I need to play a video. Everything is working fine. But if my application is sent to the background and then again to the foreground it shows a solid black screen.

Please provide me with a solution to this problem.

```
    [player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 278)];
    [player.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    [player setContentURL:outputURL];
    [player setShouldAutoplay:NO];
    player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
    player.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleNone ;

    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player pause];
    [self.view addSubview: player.view];
```

Comment: paste the code what you have tried

Comment: post your code dude! We can't see what you did without seeing your code!

Comment: @NitinGohel stop editing random code tags into posts.

Answer (score 0):

Just see this solution
[For MPMoviePlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243903/mediaplayer-framework-not-playing-video-in-ios-6/13251798#13251798)

Comment: the ploblem remains the same